# What does "Persistent Shopping Cart" do?

Tags: database, cart, persistent

We know that Magento saves a logged-in customer's shopping cart items in the database for a very long time (if not forever).

Then what's this "Persistent Shopping Cart" option for? What difference does it make? What's its advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It saves the quote ID in a long living cookie (`persistent_shopping_cart`) so that even when the session expires, **guest customers** maintain their carts.

Comment: Oh, it's only for guest customers, not logged in customers?

Comment: Yes, for logged in customers the cart is saved for unlimited time anyways

Comment: @Shawn follow up: It seems like it does not really work like that even if it *should*. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133219/does-persistent-shopping-cart-work-for-guest-unlogged-visitors/133433#133433

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it might just be a renaming (aka branding) of the existing functionality.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-a-persistent-shopping-cart

Comment: well, I have it disabled. My shopping cart items still stay there like forever.

Comment: link is broken, that's one example of why links-only answers are not helpful